# App Crash camera device rear : Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: swift, swift4

Below is the code for the rear camera, I tried adding rear camera is activated but I receive an error.

```
func addImagePickerToContainerView(){

    imagePickers = UIImagePickerController()
    if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front) {
        imagePickers?.delegate = self
        imagePickers?.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePickers?.cameraDevice = .rear
        addChildViewController(imagePickers!)

        // Add the child's View as a subview
        self.cameraContainerView.addSubview((imagePickers?.view)!)
        self.cameraContainerView.addSubview(layerKTP)
        imagePickers?.view.frame = cameraContainerView.bounds
        imagePickers?.allowsEditing = false
        imagePickers?.showsCameraControls = false
        imagePickers?.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    }
}
```

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Comment: Try to resize your image

Comment: @Ben10 I have tried to resize but still crash

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: here my code : func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}

Comment: @IrwanMadness have you find any solution?. now i am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
extension UIImage
{
 func resizeImage(toSize size:CGSize, scale:CGFloat) ->UIImage
  {
    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0), size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    self.draw(in: imageRect)
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resizedImage!
 }
}
//Use this method like
let resizedImage = selectedImg.resizeImage(toSize:CGSize(width:100.0, height:100.0), scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but app still crash with log: 
Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died,
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue